# Match a word once either beginning or ending of a pattern

Tags: android, regex

I am trying match amount in a string. The amount could either be preceded  or followed by currency. How do I match if currency matches either beginning or ending just once of the amount.

Example:

```
USD 152206.06
1,150.00 USD
```

I am using regular expression. Right now I'm able to check this two separate regex.

```
(USD|\$)\s*(-?\d+(,\d+){0,6}(\.\d+)?)
(-?\d+(,\d+){0,6}(\.\d+)?)\s*(USD|\$)
```

How to combine it on one regex? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: merge them with `|` - https://regex101.com/r/TTQLCJ/2 ?

Comment: if supported an optional at beggining and a if clause at then end may avoid to repeat the main part `((USD|\$)\s*)?(-?\d+(,\d+){0,6}(\.\d+)?)(?(1)|\s*(USD|\$))`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul thanks it works. I didn't know these type of conditioning is supported. Can you please make your comment an answer? :)

Comment: can't answer because question is closed